# Express Node.js Routing Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am building a website using Express and NodeJS. However I am facing this routing issue. This is my route I'm using in my app.js, which is expecting a parameter.

```
app.get(['/purchase/:purchaseID',], getPurchasePage)
```

And the route will link to:

```
res.render('purchase.ejs' , {
        title: "Purchase Order :" + req.param.referenceID,
        referenceID : req.param.referenceID
    })
```

However, upon accessing the link via e.g. (localhost:2000/purchase/123456), the page loads. However all external files (CSS/JavaScript/JQuery) could not be loaded.

This led me to think that there is something going on with this line of code instead:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I tried fiddling with the my routes and I managed to get it completely working with the website loading fine

```
app.get(['/purchase?id=:purchaseID',], getPurchasePage)
```

However, I would really like to use the first method I mentioned. Would like to get some help on the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and it works

head.ejs

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/app.js">
```

app.js

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Maybe you're using a relative path like js/jquery.js and not /js/jquery.js